# Terrain union to hexagon sides

Tags: modeling, mesh

thanks for taking the time to read my post.

I have a mesh terrain which i edited using the sculpt tools and found that it caused many vert issues due to their over-use (noob mistake on my part). I've spent days trying to find a quick solution as I will likely need to do the same a workflow again to another 120 hexes for my game.

Can anyone advise of the quickest way to fill in the gaps between the hex edge and the terrain mesh (2 separate objects). I am familiar with the triangulate function but having a hard time getting the mesh to combine correctly with the edge mesh even after testing pretty much all the modifiers.

The goal is to be able to remove offending polys that are in -Y axis range (below the ground of the terrain) and then use an efficient workflow to add in the missing areas quickly > triangulate > done... hopefully?

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

[image: holes between terrain mesh and sides]

[image: underside of mesh problem]
[image: problem Geometry i Since Deleted]

Comment: To add: the last image is an example of the offending polys **before** i removed them, resulting in the first two images above.

Comment: Depending on how you cut this up in first place, possibly Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123197/block-of-terrain-with-topo-on-top.  Akin to adding solidify modifier and then boolean delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can select in edit mode all the lower edge loops, extrude them and proportionally move them to the edges of the hexagon. Then use snap to edges so they adjust exactly to your sides.

Comment: Hi Thanks, i did try that and have done so again but the issue is a full edge loop cant be created- i think due to the hexSides not being part of the same object. The image shows the extent of selecting an edge while holding down ALT.

Oh, i dont think i can add any more images?

Comment: https://imgur.com/qOWEISS

Comment: https://imgur.com/2yjPHKp broken edge loop

Comment: Yes, you have to work side by side, six times.

Comment: Sure i don't mind doing that, but how do i make Blender recognise the edge loop including the hex sides... or is that not possible? Because if it were possible, i would then only have to fill the hole and triangulate which would be much faster. But if that's not possible i'll do them manually, though doing this an additional 120 times x 6 seems like a big undertaking. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In Edge select mode, holding Ctrl-Alt while selecting an edge (or two vertices) selects a sequence of edges that are not connected, but on opposite sides to each other continuing along a face loop. Can you try that?

Comment: Hi again, sorry i never realised you responded, just noticed i had to expand the comments. Anyway i tried yoru method but i am still unable to grab any edges of the HexSide object while the terrainMesh edges are selected. I have even tried parenting the hex side to the terrain, but same result.

Hence i decided to make a video which you can view here. Perhaps you can advise of any tips or what i might be doing wrong? https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hr5RFUEdt02G3pjbYDPT1gRuH9qQENWd?usp=sharing many thanks