# Heightmap on top with flat sides?

Tags: subdivision-surface, displacement, height-map

I have a plane with a Displace modifier, as well as Subdivision. I've imported a heightmap and got it to the desired height, however I'd like to make this into a solid block.

[image: heightmap created using displace and subdivide]

Essentially I want to bring the edges straight down, with totally flat sides and bottom. I've tried a few things such as extrusion, solidify and thickness, but neither worked as intended (possibly a conflict with the subdivision).

[This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123197/block-of-terrain-with-topo-on-top) looked like what I wanted, but it still doesn't provide the results I'm looking for.

If I simply extrude the outer edges down, this is the result:

https://gfycat.com/charmingbarealbino

Comment: have you tried to assign the extruded part to a vertex group, as suggested in the link you provide, or here by Marty Fouts?

Answer (score 1):

- Make a cube

In *Edit Mode*

- select the vertices of the top face of the cube.
- Create a new Vertex Group
- Assign those vertices to the new Group
- Add your Displacement Modifier
- Set it to use your new Vertex Group

[image: Cube with top face vertices selected]

[image: Vertex group that includes those vertices]

[image: Displacement Modifier using that group]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

[image]I simply used the landscape generator to generate a landscape, tabbed into edit mode, selected the bottom faces and extruded it down the Z axis

Maybe you need to apply your modifiers before extruding or apply all transformations.

[image]