# Flat surface shading artifacts

Tags: faces, normals, extrude, artifacts

To make a terrain surface into a volume, I used the instructions in [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/123199). Unfortunately, the extruded side walls and the bottom face are getting strange shading errors.

[image]
[image]

Can anyone explain to me how these occur and how I can fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the *Object Data Properties* (the green triangular symbol) and under *Geometry Data* click *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*.

[image: custom normals]

I have to admit I don't actually know how or when those "custom normals data" were created, but I experienced this from time to time, too. Maybe someone else can give an explanation on the circumstances.

Comment: One possible source (though I haven't checked to see if it seems likely in this specific case) is using the Harden Normals option when running a bevel.  That creates the split normals data.  A weighted normal modifier that has been applied will also do this, as will just about anything else that edits the normals (there's a plugin somewhere that lets you paint them with a brush, and presumably various other ways).  Those are the most common sources I can think of.  A new weighted normal modifier can sometimes be the best way to fix it, if it looks bad after deleting the custom normals.

Comment: @Ben Oh, thanks for the information. I guess the _Harden Normals_ option is most of the times the cause whenever I get this in my work.